# Keep the JavaScript loading even on scrolling

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am building a chrome Extension which loads a javascript to place an image in front of tweets only with URLs. The code below achieves the desirable, However on scrolling the page sometimes the URLs arent marked.

Any idea on this?

```
linkslist=document.body.getElementsByClassName("js-display-url");
    var i=0;
    for (var index=0;index<linkslist.length;index++)    
    {
        console.log(linkslist[index]);

            arrayoflinks[i]=linkslist[index].getAttribute("data-expanded-url") ;
            linkslist[i].innerHTML=linkslist[i].innerHTML+"<img src='"+chrome.extension.getURL("green.png")+"' alt='green'/>";
            i++;


    }
```

Comment: Your title is confusing, since it makes one assume you want to start code as soon as browser scrolls, where you actually are talking about refresh problems as i can read from text. please make question clearer.

Comment: Edited the title. Kindly review. Thanks :) The question basically is about keep loading the script even on infinite scrolling.